# Single-IC solution to the problem of spurious high on NodeMCU powerup

Tags: integrated-circuit

I am currently trying to find a method to use all the IO pins on a NodeMCU to control an 8-Relay Board. However, some pins on the board briefly switch to high during startup and that is a problem for my use. Thus I've decided to use an AND Gate IC and connected all of the Input As to a NodeMCU pin that is safe to use during boot. Is there an IC which does this or something similar internally as illustrated on the picture below (just a quickly photoshopped diagram of a 74HC08 IC)?

[image: An example of an IC I mean]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your 7408-based solution sounds fine: just connect one input of all the AND gates to the common enable pin.

Other than that, there's a lot of [74xx series octal buffers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_7400-series_integrated_circuits) with three-state output and an enable pin.  the [Cheapest I found on digikey](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/integrated-circuits-ics/logic-buffers-drivers-receivers-transceivers/704?k=&pkeyword=&sv=0&pv547=281410&sf=0&FV=-8%7C704&quantity=5&ColumnSort=1000011&page=1&stock=1&nstock=1&pageSize=25) is the [74LCX541FT](https://toshiba.semicon-storage.com/info/docget.jsp?did=15179&prodName=74LCX541FT), which has active-low enable pins, but that's not really a problem: pull them up with a resistor to Vcc, and pull them down using your microcontroller once everything is stable.

Also, since relay boards are incredibly slow in comparison to microcontrollers: The most straightforward way might be using a serial-in, parallel out shift register. That reduces the amount of NodeMCU pads needed to control your relays from 8 data pins + 1 enable to 1 clock + 1 data (+ 1 latch pin, if you're using one that doesn't automatically only latch after 8 data bits). I²C IO extenders would be another solution.

The beauty in reducing pin count is not only reduced wiring complexity, but also that you could very well opto-isolate these 2 to 3 lines; a feature that can be desirable, if the relay switching leads to any transients that you don't want to expose your nodeMCU to.

Comment: Ah yes, currently I'm connecting one input of the AND gates together but I was wondering if there was one which does it internally. I guess not. But I do have a 74HC595 that can work as a Shift Register so that's likely what I'm going to do. Thanks!

Comment: @Bryan have you read the second paragraph of my answer? There's plenty of such ICs. I even list an example.

Comment: If you don't want to get very digital, you can use your and-gates wire the second input to a single schmitt-trigger and put a RC-network on its input.